# ASPxGridView - Use image in Header Filter GridView

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I can't find a way to change the header filter icon of my gridview. Any one can help me?

[image]

Comment: show us what you did..

Comment: I think you have given multiple <th> tag

Comment: i'm using DevEpress GridView.

Comment: Before using DevExpress you need to read document http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/

Comment: i read it and i could'nt find an ansewer their, that's why i post my question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. 
GridViewSettings.Images.HeaderFilter.Url property to customize the Header Filter image